# Scan and find data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can we scan a table and find data type for it because when we load csv file into a table using import export wizard it defaults even a numeric column to varchar can we scan the table after import and find the datatype which could be ideal?

For example consider a csv file A.csv it contains

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD ColumnE
1234      xyz     123.4   1      abc123
4258      acv     785.6   0      abs58
785       fgf     879.6   1      ftrd15
448       wsd   87878.6   0      wewe
78528     ews    6968.2   1      awaq
525554    qwe       2.3   0      afgd87
```

so when I load this using import export wizard all columns are varchar but I need to scan the table and then find data type. I am not concerned about loading the data with correct data types initially I only care after I load the data into the table and then scan the table to find the data type.

Comment: SSMS data import wizard can suggest data types (Suggest Types button), but be careful as it has some limitations and makes strange assumptions sometime.

Comment: How exactly would this work with the after load?  What are going to do once you know the type -- make another table?

Comment: Yes create a new table with correct data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'd be dealing with 6 main datatypes.

1. `DATETIME`
2. `INTEGER`
3. `DECIMAL`
4. `CHARACTER`
5. `VARCHAR`
6. `BIT`

So one way to do this without explicitly trying to convert each one and catch an error, since you can't use `TRY_CONVERT` in 2008, is by using `ISDATE, ISNUMERIC`, and `CHARINDEX`. For each column, you can do something like this. Of course, you could do this in a cursor for each column, or just copy the case statement a few times, or with a cross join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
'ColumnA' as ColumnName,
CASE
   WHEN ISNUMERIC(ColumnA) = 1 AND LEN(ColumnA) = 1 AND ColumnA NOT LIKE '%[2-9]%' THEN 'Bit',
   WHEN ISNUMERIC(ColumnA) = 1 AND CHARINDEX('.',ColumnA) > 0 THEN 'Decimal'
   WHEN ISNUMERIC(ColumnA) = 1 AND CHARINDEX('.',ColumnA) = 0 THEN 'Integer'
   WHEN ISDATE(ColumnA) = 1 THEN 'Date'
   WHEN LEN(ColumnA) = 1 AND ColumnA LIKE '%[a-z]%' THEN 'Character'
   ELSE 'VARCHAR'
END AS DataTypeCheck
FROM YourTable
```

It's not perfect since we aren't checking all data types, but it should get you started at least. You can add some more `LEN()` functions to figure out what you want to set your `DECIMAL` length and precision to, as well as your `VARCHAR()` length. However, there is no way of knowing if a follow on insert would cause binary data to be truncated... since the values are unknown. So you'd just need to set these field lengths to be large enough to accept any follow on input. Also this will give you all possible data types for that column. so if you have 12 and 12.34 it will return `INT` and `DECIMAL`, in which you should choose `DECIMAL`. This can be taken care of in a follow on query if need be.

Comment: thank you so much for you reply this helps my cause a lot one last question how to determine a boolean column?

Comment: @Zack you use `BIT` which can be `0,1,or NULL`. I added this to the first line of the case statement.

Answer (score 1):

This question is highly problematic. The destination / intended-use of the data determines the datatype, not an incomplete scan of the data. *You* should be determining what the datatypes are, not error-prone code (and any code *will* be error-prone). For example, what should the datatype be for `20122010`:

1. INT / BIGINT
2. FLOAT
3. VARCHAR(1 - 8000)
4. VARBINARY(1 - 8000)
5. DATE / DATETIME?  (Is it `YYYYDDMM` or `DDMMYYYY`?)

What about `12ab`:

1. VARCHAR(1 - 8000)
2. VARBINARY(1 - 8000)

What about `true`:

1. VARCHAR(1 - 8000)
2. BIT

And relying upon `ISNUMERIC` is unreliable as it returns `1` for values that won't convert. For example, in some cultures, the comma is used instead of a period to indicate decimal, hence the following is a valid currency amount, but it doesn't convert the way one would expect it to in that case:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('212012,00'); -- 1
SELECT CONVERT(MONEY, '212012,95') AS [Money]; -- 21201295.00
```

Or, if using the code in the accepted answer, the following would be considered a valid "Integer":

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, '212012,00') AS [Int]; -- error
-- Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
-- Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '212012,00' to data type int.
```

What about this:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('212,012.00,0,1'); -- 1
```

Comment: Coding for the commas is easy. Not sure why you stressed it so much. Everyone said that the OP shouldn't go about it this way. I even stated it wasn't perfect. Thanks for the reiteration with examples. They are good examples

Comment: @scsimon The source is a CSV file, so maybe the "numbers" won't have embedded commas, which removes a bit of the complication. Still, I thought there were other "odd" behaviors of `ISNUMERIC` that made it unreliable, beyond the commas. But I didn't stress that as the main point. I gave a few examples where the type _can't_ be determined based on the values. There's just too much ambiguity for any solution to work. I know you said it was a good start and not perfect. The problem isn't your solution, it's the request. It makes _no_ sense ETLing data into a system without knowing what it is.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on how many different data types you want to support you can use a combination of `convert()` function with `datalength()` to discover what a column can be converted to successfully, and find out the proper data type looking at the percentage of successfully converted records vs total.

But I still recommend discovering the types before loading to avoid wasting time and storage resources, as I commented earlier.

Comment: I think it is easier than that if it is one time (not clear by the question) you can just do a `SELECT cast(columna as integer) FROM table` and see if it reports an error.

Comment: Yeah, if it's one time, and small dataset... We do not have complete requirements from the OP. And then there is this whole can of worms called "dirty data".

Comment: Understatement of the year. :D